# How do I use WebView2 in a console application

Tags: c#, webview2

```
string text = "return 'test';";
var webView = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null).RunSynchronously();
var srun = webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(text);
```

When I run the above code EnsureCoreWebView2Async is getting this exception

> "Cannot change thread mode after it is set. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80010106 (RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE))"

What do I need to do to run this with out a winform dlg in a console or windows service?

Comment: It probably needs a SynchronizationContext, so it can capture an execution Context (its Scheduler) it can resume to. `RunSynchronously()` cannot be used here.

Comment: Just as a reference, it seems that using `HWND_MESSAGE` as described in [#202](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/202) allows to use WebView2 headless e.g. in a .NET Console application.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out the key thing is to add `[STAThread]` to the `Main` function.

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webView21 = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();

        var ecwTask = webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        while (ecwTask.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        };

        var scriptText = @"var test = function(){ return 'apple';}; test();";
        var srunTask = webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(scriptText);
        while (srunTask.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        };

        Console.WriteLine(srunTask.Result);
    }
}
```

Other items that maybe note worthy,

- Sometimes you need to set the bitness of the application because use
  of AnyCPU will cause an infinite wait when creating the WebView2 COM
  object.
- You may need to set the webview2 source property to foce the
  instance into existance.

Comment: I just learned, **DON'T** use `async Task Main()`, because [it doesn't work with `STAThread`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22112). _(Took me 1 hour to find this bug.)_